# Why does wireshark show only local destination ip adresses while connecting to remote website on company network

Tags: networking, wireshark

I am trying to capture packets on company network. The problem is that I can only see local destination packets while capturing. You can see the result in the following picture:

[image]

What do you think is the problem with the capture?

Comment: Get Wire Shark running and then pull up Amazon. Do you see it?  I use Comm View (a commercial packet sniffer) and it shows me Amazon and external sites just fine.

Comment: I see only local traffic beginning with 10...

Comment: Amazon is not local traffic. So you say Wire Shark only shows you local?

Comment: Yes I see only local traffic even when joining remote websites

Comment: "You will only capture "local" traffic on your WiFi connection unless you get an AirPcap adapter or a NIC that will go into RFMON mode."   Are you using wireless?  https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/26334/wireshark-is-just-capturing-local-traffic#:~:text=You%20will%20only%20capture%20%22local,will%20go%20into%20RFMON%20mode.&text=Ethernet%20traffic%20nowadays%20work%20mostly,broadcasts%20and%20your%20own%20traffic.

Comment: Assuming you are on wireless, the most recent comment I posted is the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm capturing on Ethernet is there something similar?

Comment: Forgot to mention in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your company likely implements a proxy on all of your internet traffic (`10.24.242.50:8080`) so all of your HTTP/HTTPS traffic is being routed to the proxy rather than out to the internet.

So, I don't think there is anything wrong with the capture, your machine is just making a connection the the proxy server instead of the one you're expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. How does the proxy know what ip address to join if it doesnt have it. I think I should see the destination ip and it should be changed by the proxy.

Comment: Get and try a USB Wireless adapter to move your connection away from the company and test the idea.

Comment: I get the picture, but I think that it cannot work if I dont send the ip address out on internet. I can join websites, but I'm not capturing any packets with an ip address which goes to these websites.

Comment: @user123 a proxy is setup on your computer by your company or sometimes just by connecting to the company network.  They configure your computer to send all of your traffic to a specific IP address within the company network.  The proxy then makes the connection out to the internet on your behalf and forwards the traffic you send on out to the internet.  Companies typically do this so they can implement content filtering and compliance and security policies.  These proxies are very common in large enterprises as well as schools and government offices.

Comment: @heavyd If the proxy is setup in the computer, can I disable it. I gained admin rights over the computer.

Comment: @user123 you may be able to (check your proxy settings in your browser) but its likely that your company is blocking any internet access that doesn't go through the proxy